# Calculation with GROUP and SUBSELECT not giving right value

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have an issue to get a properly calculated value from my query... I have 3 tables:

Table match:

| id | idEvent | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | completed |
| 2 | 6 | completed |
| 3 | 6 | completed |

Table match2player:

| idMatch | idPlayer | party |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 32 | "0" |
| 1 | 53 | "0" |
| 1 | 55 | "1" |
| 1 | 56 | "1" |
| 2 | 8 | "0" |
| 2 | 52 | "0" |
| 2 | 54 | "1" |
| 2 | 57 | "1" |
| 3 | 8 | "0" |
| 3 | 32 | "0" |
| 3 | 54 | "1" |
| 3 | 55 | "1" |

Table set:

| idMatch | index | partySetWon |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | "0" |
| 1 | 2 | "1" |
| 1 | 3 | "0" |
| 2 | 1 | "1" |
| 2 | 2 | "1" |
| 3 | 1 | "1" |
| 3 | 2 | "0" |
| 3 | 3 | "1" |

The following query is throwing the output underneath:

```
SELECT 
    `match2player`.`idPlayer` AS 'Player',
    COUNT(DISTINCT `match`.`id`) AS 'Matches played',

    SUM(IF(`match2player`.`party`=
    (SELECT set1.`partySetWon` FROM `tennisdb`.`set` set1 WHERE set1.`idMatch` = `set`.`idMatch` GROUP BY set1.`partySetWon` ORDER BY COUNT(set1.`partySetWon`) DESC LIMIT 1)
    ,1,0)) AS 'Matches Won',
    
    SUM(IF(`match2player`.`party`=`set`.`partySetWon`, 1, 0)) AS 'Sets Won',
    SUM(IF(`match2player`.`party`<>`set`.`partySetWon`, 1, 0)) AS 'Sets lost'
FROM `tennisdb`.`set`
LEFT JOIN `tennisdb`.`match` ON `match`.`id` = `set`.`idMatch`
LEFT JOIN `tennisdb`.`match2player` ON `match2player`.`idMatch` = `set`.`idMatch`
WHERE `match`.`idEvent` = 6 AND `match`.`status` IN ('completed','awarded')
GROUP BY `match2player`.`idPlayer`
ORDER BY Player;

Player,"Matches played","Matches Won","Sets Won","Sets lost"
8,2,0,1,4
32,2,3,3,3
52,1,0,0,2
53,1,3,2,1
54,2,5,4,1
55,2,3,3,3
56,1,0,1,2
57,1,2,2,0
```

The column "Matches won" is giving wrong value (too high) and I have no idea how to solve... I played with further groupings, windows, etc., none was delivering expected result...

The subselect shall identify which party won the majority of sets, and resulting the match. This works okay when I on top group over the matches (and not only the player). But I am not looking for a breakdown of individual matches, I want to get the stats over all matches...

Comment: Can you update your post with the expected output?

Comment: Player 8, 52 and 56 didn't win any match and 0 is given, so that's correct.
Player 32, 53, 55 and 57 won all 1 match, but values of 2 or 3 are given -> incorrect (should be 1 instead).
Player 54 won 2 matches, but value 5 is given -> incorrect (should be 2 instead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analyze matches in inner query and then sum sets, matches won and lost:

```
select idplayer, sum(case when setwon > setlost then 1 else 0 end) mwon,
       sum(case when setwon < setlost then 1 else 0 end) mlost,
       sum(setwon) swon, sum(setlost) slost
from (
  select mp.idmatch, idplayer, 
         sum(case party when partysetwon then 1 else 0 end) setwon,  
         sum(case party when partysetwon then 0 else 1 end) setlost  
  from match2player mp 
  join `set` s on s.idmatch = mp.idmatch 
  group by mp.idmatch, idplayer) grp
group by idplayer order by idplayer
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/El0Ic1kN)